# how passing props to a private route with out ignoring the redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a private route component that will open to the layout page if i have a user and if not it will redirect to the landing page route which is the the sign in page. The problem is I have a function on my app page that is called by my layout page so I passed it to the layout page as props like so

```
  <PrivateRoute>
     <Layout send_id={send_id}/>
   </PrivateRoute>
```

But when I do this it ignores the redirect in the private route

```
export default function PrivateRoute({component :Component, ...rest}) {
const {currentUser} = useAuth()

console.log({currentUser})
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props=>{
           return currentUser ? <Component {...props}/> :<Redirect to="/landingPage" />
        }}
        >
        
    </Route>
)
```

}

but when I change the route on the app page back to what i had before adding the function it works perfectly

```
 <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component = {Layout}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the component to the children field, this is children props, not a component props.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({children :Component, ...rest}) {
const {currentUser} = useAuth()

console.log({currentUser})
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props=>{
           return currentUser ? <Component {...props}/> :<Redirect to="/landingPage" />
        }}
        >
        
    </Route>
)
```